# What does Ï mean in a play?

Tags: symbols

I just saw this in a play that I'm reading (on page 24 of [this version](http://www.sfponline.org/uploads/70/AViewFromtheBridge.pdf) of *A View From the Bridge* by Arthur Miller):

> *Enter* **Beatrice** *with coffee. ï*

What does the *ï* represent or mean? I can't find it anywhere else in the text when someone enters a scene.

Comment: Do you have any more examples? My guess would be that it's a character encoding error, but the rest of the document seems rather well formatted...

Comment: I agree with @curiousdannii that this is likely a character encoding error. I'm trying to figure out which, but the only *common* context I find ï mis-encoded is in Unicode byte order marks (BOMs), which is clearly not the car here. Maybe it's worth asking over on [TeX.se], and have them look at the PDF source to  tell you what's going on and what was intended? I found a [webpage with another example of ï misused as a separator](http://www.applelinks.com/index.php/comments/12005/), which was likely unintentional, but as I'm on a phone I can't view the source to see what was intended.

Comment: Correct version here:https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Fx5aAAAAMAAJ&q=%22enter+beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22enter+beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uH1DVbLcC4bvatO4gKAI&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It may, as curiousdanni says, be some problem with the character encoding or some other issue with the creation of the PDF from whatever the original source file was. Or it may just be a typo: somebody accidentally hit an extra key when editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to determine whether this is (1) an arcane but possibly meaningful abbreviation or (2) just a stray character is to see how other editions of the play handle the same line. Here are ten that I checked in Google Books:

[*Arthur Miller's Collected Plays: With an Introduction*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RQtaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEISTAJ) (1957), page 395:

> *Enter Beatrice with coffee.*

[*The Modern Theater*](https://books.google.com/books?id=V_Ri15Sl9ugC&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEILjAD) (1964), page 1261:

> (*Enter* BEATRICE *with coffee*)

[*The Art of Modern Drama*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OHNkAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIMzAE) (1969), page 188:

> [*Enter* BEATRICE *with coffee*.]

[*Mandala*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ES28907QBcYC&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIQTAH) (1970), page 467:

> [*Enter* BEATRICE *with coffee*.]

[*The Living Art: An Introduction to Theatre and Drama*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6WwbAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIOTAF) (1971), page 467:

> [*Enter* **Beatrice** *with coffee*.]

[*The Forms of Drama*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W6InAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIRTAI) (1972), page 330:

> (*Enter* BEATRICE *with coffee*.)

[*Drama and Discussion*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXtWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIPTAG) (1978), page 257:

> [*Enter* BEATRICE *with coffee*.]

[*A View from the Bridge*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6tX7hVV0kYQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Enter%20Beatrice%20with%20coffee%22&f=false) (1995), page 20:

> *Enter* BEATRICE *with coffee*.

[*A View from the Bridge*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9hl1gtak_-8C&pg=PT40&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22Enter%20Beatrice%20with%20coffee%22&f=false) (20011), unpaginated:

> *Enter* beatrice *with coffee*.

[*The Penguin Arthur Miller: Collected Plays*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VLSaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT400&dq=%22Enter+Beatrice+with+coffee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5bK-lP_OAhVPHGMKHbihDqIQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22Enter%20Beatrice%20with%20coffee%22&f=false) (2015), unpaginated:

> *Enter Beatrice with coffee.*

There is actually a rather impressive range of differences in the typographic presentation of this stage instruction across the ten editions I checked. But not one of them follows the instruction with a bunch of letterspaces and then the character *ï*—which leads me to conclude that, in your edition of the book, the *ï* is simply a stray character not in the original but picked up by accident at some point in the publishing process.